# How to return only the MATCHED DATA from a SQL Server Full-Text search?

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, hit-highlighting

So I've researched SO regarding "hit highlighting", and it appears to be close to what I want. But nobody seems to have a clear method to simply return JUST the matched data from the FTS search.

So I'm asking specifically - since all the other posts I've found about it have been a bit wonky or simply not functional.

Thanks...

Comment: Wow.. has this become a stumper??

Comment: Hit highlighting is a feature currently not supported in SQL Server. There are other third-party options(such as ThinkHighlight) which claim to do that. 

http://www.interactivethoughts.com/products/thinkhighlight/